# How to find which API does a cordova plugin uses

Tags: javascript, phonegap-plugins, dropbox-api

I have been handed over a project which uses a cordova plugin https://github.com/rossmartin/phonegap-dropbox-sync-android to provide Dropbox functionality. I heard about the Dropbox API V1 is being deprecated. So I need to find out which version of Sync API does this plugin use?

Answer (score 1):

The last commit is from April 2015, so its most likely V1, as V2 wasn't launched till October 2015 from some casual browsing. I would *highly* suggest not using such a dated plugin either way, as there will be no support for issues.

Comment: That's correct. Specifically, [it seems to use](https://github.com/rossmartin/phonegap-dropbox-sync-android/blob/master/src/Android/dropbox-sync-sdk-android.jar) the [Dropbox Android Sync SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/sync/sdks/android) jar, which does use API v1 and is deprecated. It will stop working [once API v1 is retired](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

> https://github.com/hazemhagrass/phonegap-dropbox-sync-plugin

plugin for dropbox sync for both platform iOS and android.